# Ativar BCMath para instalar o zabbix

Tags: php, zabbix

Estou tentando instalar o zabbix no meu notebook ubuntu 18.04 e na hora de configurar no browser aparece essa messagem
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

já usei esse comando no terminal `apt-get install php-bcmath`e depois reiniciei o apache e não deu certo, como poderei ativar?

Comment: Tente `sudo apt-get install php7.0-bcmath`, `sudo apt-get install php7.1-bcmatch` ou `sudo apt-get install php7.2-bcmath` etc. Depende a sua versão do PHP. Sem informá-la, fica difícil.

Comment: sudo apt-get install php7.0-bcmatch
Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto
Construindo árvore de dependências
Lendo informação de estado... Pronto
E: Impossível encontrar o pacote php7.0-bcmatch
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.0-bcmatch'
E: Não foi possível encontrar o pacote através da expressão regular 'php7.0-bcmatch'

Quando coloco 7.1 ou 7.2 dá mesma resposta

Comment: Qual a versão do seu PHP `php -v`? Você também pode usar o comando `sudo apt-cache search bcmath`

Comment: Esta aqui PHP 7.1.15-0

Comment: Então você pode usar o `sudo ... php7.1-bcmath` Ou o `apt-cache` como foi citado.

Comment: apt-cache php7.1-bcmath?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install php7.1-bcmath` **caso não funcione** use `sudo apt-cache search bcmath` para ver quais opções você pode utilizar.

Comment: `daniel@DanielPC:~$ sudo apt-cache search bcmath`
`php-bcmath - Bcmath module for PHP [default]`
`php7.2-bcmath - Bcmath module for PHP`
`daniel@DanielPC:~$ sudo apt-get install php7.2-bcmatch`
`Lendo listas de pacotes... Pronto`
`Construindo árvore de dependências`
`Lendo informação de estado... Pronto`
`E: Impossível encontrar o pacote php7.2-bcmatch`
`E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.2-bcmatch'`
`E: Não foi possível encontrar o pacote através da expressão regular 'php7.2-bcmatch'`

Comment: pacote não encontrado

Comment: @ValdeirPsr consegui resolver, atualizei o php para a versão 2 e depois usei o comando sudo `apt-get install php7.2-bcmath` e o problema foi resolvido, muito obrigado pela ajuda!

Answer (score 0):

@ValdeirPsr consegui resolver, atualizei o php para a versão 2 e depois usei o comando sudo `apt-get install php7.2-bcmath` e o problema foi resolvido, muito obrigado pela ajuda!